# Is there a curve of fastest ascent (under a uniform field of force) analogous to the Brachistocrone curve?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, optimization

I was working on creating a flight plan for a small rc plane, I was wondering what would be the fastest way to ascend from a lower point to a higher point. Is the answer analogous to the brachistochrone curve? I have been out of touch from calculus for a bit so it'll take time for me learn it and try to figure the answer out on my own.